# Get the object of the function javascript

Tags: javascript, this

Suppose I have **a obj called myObj** and it has a function test

```
MyObj.prototype.test = function(){
     alert(this);
}
```

And I set the timer:

```
setInteravl(myObj.test,1000);
```

As this depends entirely on how you called the function, this refers to window instead of myObj in the alert statement

**What should I do if I need the myObj reference instead?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
var myObj = new MyObj();

setInterval(function() {myObj.test();}, 1000);
```

---

Or in modern implementations, `bind` it.

```
var myObj = new MyObj();

setInterval(myObj.test.bind(myObj), 1000);
```

Comment: Note that in addition to solving the `this` problem, wrapping your function call in an anonymous function provides a way to pass parameters to your function (given that `setInterval` and `setTimeout` obviously don't know anything about your function's parameters).

Comment: @nnnnnn: Very true and worth noting.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a `function`:

```
setInteravl(function () {myObj.test()} ,1000);
```